# How to properly call `fetchAllSubscriptionsOperation()` to retrieve CloudKit subscriptions?

Tags: ios, cloudkit, subscriptions

I am trying to get all the subscriptions associated with the current user. [According to the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckfetchsubscriptionsoperation/1515282-fetchallsubscriptionsoperation), the function to call is:

```
CKFetchSubscriptionsOperation.fetchAllSubscriptionsOperation()
```

I call the function this way:

```
    let op = CKFetchSubscriptionsOperation.fetchAllSubscriptionsOperation()
    op.fetchSubscriptionCompletionBlock = { (subs, error) in
        print("*** fetched subs: \(subs)")
    }
    let q = OperationQueue()
    q.addOperation(op)
```

However, the `subs` parameter returns an empty dictionary (`Optional([:])`). The `error` param is `nil`. I'm new to using `NSOperation`, so I'm wondering if I am doing something wrong.

(As confirmation that subscriptions exist to be retrieved, I separately call the container's `publicDatabase.fetchAllSubscriptions()` function. This one returns the current user's subscriptions as expected. Unfortunately, it also returns the subscriptions associated with every other user in the schema.)

Comment: If `subs` is `nil` then you should look at `error`? What's the error?

Comment: Ah, sorry. `subs` is an empty dictionary. `error` is nil. (Updated original post.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sample code does not set the container and the database on the `CKFetchSubscriptionsOperation`. And since you are adding the operation to your own OperationQueue, you need to set these.

#### Option #1:

Set the container and the database on the operation directly.

```
let op = CKFetchSubscriptionsOperation.fetchAllSubscriptionsOperation()
op.fetchSubscriptionCompletionBlock = { (subs, error) in
    print("*** fetched subs: \(subs)")
}
op.container = CKContainer.default()
op.database = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
let q = OperationQueue()
q.addOperation(op)
```

#### Option #2:

Add the operation to the desired database's queue (which sets these for you).

```
let op = CKFetchSubscriptionsOperation.fetchAllSubscriptionsOperation()
op.fetchSubscriptionCompletionBlock = { (subs, error) in
    print("*** fetched subs: \(subs)")
}
CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase.add(op)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I think this may be it. I will confirm later today if it solves my problem.

Comment: Actually, why wait!? I just tried it and it worked! Thank you so much. You just saved me from setting up a complete other private db record for syncing up subscriptions as a temporary workaround . Would you happen to know where this can be found in Apple's documentation? Just want to know if I could have found it if I looked properly. Thank you again!

Comment: Look at the documentation for the [`database` property of CKDatabaseOperation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckdatabaseoperation/1515274-database). (CKFetchSubscriptionsOperation is a subclass of CKDatabaseOperation.)